# Bokeh - how to set locale for datepicker and datetime axis

Tags: python, locale, bokeh

Is there any way to localize the built-in datepicker widget and the datetime axis ?
As per [this](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/formatters.html) **current** locale should be used; but somehow, it has no effect.
Any clues ?